# Как узнать IP адрес компьютера который мог бы идентифицировать его в глобальной сети?

Tags: ip

Написал сервер на Java, со стороны клиента использую подключение к IPv4 адресу, прочел что это  локальный адрес и компьютеры вне моей сети не смогут по нему связываться. Проверил на практике, в действительности общение клиент-серверного приложения по такому IP адресу работает только если запускать и клиент и сервер на одном компьютере

Comment: Набрать в гугле: my ip

Comment: Если вы явно не арендовали у провайдера "белый" адрес, то скорее всего у вас и нет ip, идентифицируещего вас в глобальной сети. Практически у всех провайдеров это отдельная услуга. Но чаще для размещения своего сервера просто арендуют хостинг, у которого белый ip идёт в комплекте.

Comment: https://192-168-1-1.ru/ip-address-classify/

Comment: Можете подсказать пожалуйста, на каком хостинге можно разместить java код?